# assigning the model list property value to the variable in MVC view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, canvas

I am using a model named as Mdl_home_page the model consist of bunch of properties like :

```
public class Mdl_home_page
{
   public SelectList LocationSelectList { get; set; }
   public List<tbl_devices> lstOfDevices { get; set; }
}
```

The tbl_devices is my another model which contains information about devices.
The tbl_device model is :

```
public partial class tbl_devices
{
   public int device_id { get; set; }
   public string device_name { get; set; }
   public string device_ip { get; set; }
   public string device_type { get; set; }
   public string device_placement_coordinates_x { get; set; }
   public string device_placement_coordinates_y { get; set; }
}
```

I passed the model to the view like this:

```
@model SymphonyWebServer.Models.Mdl_Home_page
```

Now I have a HTML canvas on which I have an image of map where I want to display the rectangles to depict placement of a device. to do this I want to use device_placement_coordinates_x and device_placement_coordinates_y properties of tbl_device model.
So, I made a code like :

```
        var xvalue = 100, yvalue = 100;
        for (var i = 0; i < @Model.lstOfDevices.Count; i++) {
            xvalue = @Model.lstOfDevices[i].device_placement_coordinates_x;
            yvalue = @Model.lstOfDevices[i].device_placement_coordinates_y;
            ctx.fillRect(xvalue, yvalue,50,50);
        }
```

ctx is my context object of the canvas.
But It is giving me error:  the name 'i' does not exist in the current context.

Please help to resolve the problem !

Comment: I would specify integer rather than var for the indexing variable i. that is, @for(int i = 0...

Comment: or use `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `i` is an JavaScript variable. You can't use it as the index in the C# `listOfDevices` array.

Why not just loop through the array using `foreach`, and run JavaScript code inside? You can use `@:` or `<text />` to switch between C# Razor mode and JavaScript mode.

```js
var xValue = 100, yValue = 100;

@foreach (var device in Model.lstOfDevices)
{
    <text>
        xValue = @device.device_placement_coordinates_x;
        yValue = @device.device_placement_coordinates_y;
        ctx.fillRect(xValue, yValue, 50, 50);
    </text>
}
```

Comment: Thank you buddy ! Actually I didn't know that how can I switch between razor mode and js mode. Thank you for teaching me that as well.